# setting booster in a XGBClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I read the docs,

```
import xgboost as xgb
class xgboost.XGBClassifier(max_depth=3, learning_rate=0.1,
n_estimators=100, silent=True, objective='binary:logistic',
booster='gbtree', n_jobs=1,nthread=None, gamma=0, min_child_weight=1,
max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1, 
reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, base_score=0.5, 
random_state=0, seed=None, missing=None, **kwargs)
```

Then I try to create my own instance following the API

```
model_benchmark=xgb.XGBClassifier(booster ='linear',objective='binary:logistic')
```

and I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'booster'
```

Any suggestion on how to choose my desired booster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I checked the Github source code for v0.6 , and did not find anything related to booster parameter. The parameter is in the release for the latest version. However, there are some information on the Booster object in 0.6 release as well but it is probably more complex to utilize than how it is implemented the latest version.

---

According to the documentation (http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html):

```
booster: string
Specify which booster to use: gbtree, gblinear or dart.
```

There's no "linear", it should be "gblinear".

Comment: thanks. But of course it does not solve. See traceback. The entire booster arg in unexpected

Comment: @ErroriSalvo What xgboost version are you using? It might be a version issue as well, try to update to the latest version and try again.

Comment: 0.6. I absolutely can't update. I hope just the name has changed since this is a key property of xgboost... :(

Comment: @ErroriSalvo I checked the github source code for v0.6, and did not find anything related to booster parameter. The parameter is in the release for the latest version. However, there are some information on the Booster object in 0.6 release as well but it is probably more complex to utilize than how it is implemented the latest version.

Comment: thanks this is great. maybe you could make this comment the answer?

Answer (score 1):

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/py-xgboost

The above can be used to install 0.80 version of xgboost on Anaconda which has the booster parameter.

Comment: it would works till version 0.90